# Android testing : updating listview in a broadcast receiver onreceive

Tags: android, listview, testing, broadcastreceiver, android-context

MyListActivity.java has a private BroadcastReceiver which updates a ListView as soon as it receives a broadcast. I want to test whether the listview gets updated after the broadcast is received. But I am having issues with MockContext.

This is what my test looks like.

```
public class MyListActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MyListActivity>{
public void setUp()
{
    super.setUp();

    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

    mActivity = getActivity();
    myList = (ListView) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.myList);
        mContext = new MockContext();

}

public void testListUpdate()
{
    Intent in = new Intent("LIST_ITEM");
    in.putExtra("ITEM_VAL", "test2");

    try {
        Method method = MyListActivity.class.getMethod("getReceiver", null);
        BroadcastReceiver br = (BroadcastReceiver)method.invoke(mActivity, null);

        assertNotNull(br);

                    ArrayList<Item> list = new ArrayList<Item>();
                    list.add(new Item("test1"));
        ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(mActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);     
            myList.setAdapter(adapter);

        br.onReceive(mContext, in);
        assertEquals(myList.getAdapter().getCount(), 1);
    }
            catch {..}
}
```

This gives me a CalledFromWrongThreadException, I guess because the adapter should be initialized and set in the MockContext instance mContext. But if I replace the parameter mActivity in ArrayAdapter constructor with mContext, it throws an UnsupportedOperationException in ArrayAdapter.init-> MockContext.getSystemService.

Please tell me how I can initialize the adapter in the same context as that of the receiver, so that the adapter gets updated after the onReceive and I can check if the adapter size increased by 1?

One option I have is to just monitor my datasource, whether it gets updated or not, but then my onReceive calls add to adapter, which is the one that throws the error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run something on the UI thread, you may want to call [runTestOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html#runTestOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29):

```
runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Here the actions you want to perform
    }
});
```

This will avoid CalledFromWrongThreadException

Comment: That worked, even though I am still having trouble accessing the correct count of the adapter. It seems to be on a different thread, maybe. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never mind. Fixed it. Had to change my onReceive to get the latest adapter, and to add to that! Thanks a ton for your help!!

Comment: Maybe call notifyDataSetChanged of the adapter, and tell me if the number returned by getCount() is OK.

Comment: I didn't need the notifyDataSetChanged. I could retrieve the number by just the listview.getAdapter().getCount(). It worked .. thanks so much for your help once again!